# R: calling a system command

Tags: r, system, mothur

I was trying to invoke an executable from within R code using the system command. If I use command line in a terminal to invoke R, and then execute `system("mothur")`. However, if from within an R script (on RStudio) I execute the same command, I get: `sh: mothur: command not found`.

In both cases, the current working directory is the same.

Do I need to invoke the command in a different manner?

thanks!

Comment: You do have execution rights on "mothur", right?

Comment: what is the output of: system("which mothur"), system("pwd"), system("whoami")

Comment: Stephan, Yes I have the rights. The executable mothur runs ok in an R terminal window - just not when I try to run it through a script using RStudio.

Comment: Andrew - nothing is printed/returned for the first command. The second and third command return expected values: /Users/bsmith
& bsmith

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuggling to replicate this problem on my own system, but I think the answer would be to call `which` and use the output to open the application. This should work if `which` provides the correct path when used in the system command line:

```
system("$(which mothur)")
```