# How to invoke a system command in R on shared computing cluster?

Tags: r, system-calls, singularity-container

I am attempting to call a system command from within an R script. The system command I want to call is a name of a software that I load as a module on a shared computing cluster (using singularity). The problem I am having is that the software is not able to run when I use the system command.

system_trial.R) has only one line:

`system('STAR')`

```
hostname[1] Rscript system_trial.R
sh: STAR: command not found
Warning message:
In system("STAR") : error in running command
```

Of course, the software works if I call it from the shell directly.

```
hostname[2] STAR
Usage: STAR  [options]... --genomeDir /path/to/genome/index/   --readFilesIn R1.fq R2.fq
Spliced Transcripts Alignment to a Reference (c) Alexander Dobin, 2009-2020
```

- If I run `which STAR`, I get `singularity exec /apps/singularity-3/star/star-2.7.5a--0.sif STAR $@`
- Replacing `system('STAR')` with `system('singularity exec /apps/singularity-3/star/star-2.7.5a--0.sif STAR $@')` actually executes the software.
- Replacing `system('STAR')` with `system('which STAR')`, returns `which: no STAR in (/bin:etc...)`
- Using `system2('STAR')` gives `sh: STAR: command not found`.

I would like to simply use `system('STAR')`. How can I achieve this?

Related post without an answer: [R: calling a system command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761843/r-calling-a-system-command)

Comment: Have you tried [`system2`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html)?

Comment: How about system("$(which STAR)")? It's close to your third option, but invokes a shell within the command to evaluate and return `which STAR`.

Comment: @JayAchar, this did not work either.

Comment: Have you compared running `system("echo $PATH")` with running `echo $PATH` from terminal?

Comment: Also, maybe look into `.bashrc` or similar (I have no experience with singularity) if there is a link from `STAR` to `singularity exec ....` if so, I think R's `system()` doesn't source `.bashrc` et al. which would mean you have to either source it by hand or create the reference otherwise.

Comment: @iich, did you ever resolve the issue here? A recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76905897/3358272 that might be similar (the `system(.)` call is erring on a cluster node).